# How to return multiple LEFT JOIN records?

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

Suppose I have a table called `competition_rounds` which contains all the `rounds` of a `competition` available in a specific `season`:

[image]

I want return all the `round_id` available in this table, the problem is that I know only a `round_id`, so in this case `542`.

If you look at the record, you can see that this round is associated to `1607` season. I need to return also the round_id = 543, 544, 545.

I tried with no luck this:

```
$query = "SELECT r.id
FROM `competition_rounds`
LEFT JOIN competition_rounds r ON r.id = :round_id
LEFT JOIN competition_seasons s ON s.id = r.season_id
WHERE r.id = 542";

$sql = $this->db->prepare($query);

$sql->bindParam("round_id", $args["round_id"]);
$sql->execute();

$result = $sql->fetchAll();
return $response->withJson($result);
```

but this will return the same round pass as parameter multiple times...

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to write a subquery to get `season_id` by `id` then use 
subquery `season_id` to get data.

I have a question, why would you want to `LEFT JOIN competition_seasons` table, because you didn't use any column from it.

```
SELECT r.id
FROM `competition_rounds` r
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT r.season_id season_id 
    FROM competition_rounds r 
    WHERE r.id = 542
) t ON r.season_id = t.season_id
LEFT JOIN competition_seasons s ON s.id = r.season_id
```

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose I have a table called competition_rounds which contains all
>   the rounds of a competition available in a specific season:
>
> I want return all the round_id available in this table, the problem is
>   that I know only a round_id, so in this case 542.

Assuming the image is your table and data. 
This query should do the trick.

```
SELECT
 competition_rounds.round_id
FROM 
 competition_rounds 
WHERE
 competition_rounds.season_id
IN (    
  SELECT 
   competition_rounds.season_id
  FROM 
   competition_rounds
  WHERE 
   competition_rounds.id = 542
)
```